# How do I handle trying to read non-existent fileswithout a segfault in c?

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I am writing code to check if a file is real and to read it if it is real

```
#include <stdio.h>
char file[100];
FILE* thefile;
int main(){
        thefile = fopen("what.txt", "r");
        if (thefile == NULL){
                printf("No File");
        } else {
                fgets(file, 100, thefile);
                printf("%s", file);
        }
        fclose(thefile);
        return 0;


}
```

It returns a segfault, how would I handle this and not open file if it does not exist?

I've tried moving the expression into the if statement, and about every tutorial I could find.

Comment: Don't call `fclose` on a non-open file.

Answer (score 0):

If the call to `fopen()` fails, `fclose()` shall be called with a `NULL` pointer argument, which would invoke undefined behavior.

We should exit the program if `fopen()` returns `NULL`:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

thefile = fopen("what.txt", "r");
if (thefile == NULL) {
    /* Write error messages to stderr. 
     * Calling strerror() or perror() can be more helpful. 
     */
    fprintf (stderr, "No File.\n"); 
    return EXIT_FAILURE; /* ADD. *?
}
/* Rest of the code. */
```